# Warning: Attempt to read property "total" on array

Tags: php

i'm trying to load the sales, discount the stock and this error comes up

> Warning: Attempt to read property "total" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\veterinaria\terminarVenta.php on line 28
>
> Warning: Attempt to read property "id" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\veterinaria\terminarVenta.php on line 29
>
> Warning: Attempt to read property "cantidad" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\veterinaria\terminarVenta.php on line 29

`

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST["total"])) exit;


session_start();


$total = $_POST["total"];
include_once "conexion.php";


$ahora = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas(fecha, total) VALUES (?, ?);");
$sentencia->execute([$ahora, $total]);

$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("SELECT id FROM ventas ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
$sentencia->execute();
$resultado = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$idVenta = $resultado === false ? 1 : $resultado->id;
var_dump($_SESSION["carrito"]);

$base_de_datos->beginTransaction();
$sentencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("INSERT INTO productos_vendidos(id_producto, id_venta, cantidad) VALUES (?, ?, ?);");
$sentenciaExistencia = $base_de_datos->prepare("UPDATE productos SET existencia = existencia - ? WHERE id = ?;");
foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $producto) {
    $total += $producto->total;
    $sentencia->execute([$producto->id, $idVenta, $producto->cantidad]);
    $sentenciaExistencia->execute([$producto->cantidad, $producto->id]);
}
$base_de_datos->commit();
unset($_SESSION["carrito"]);
$_SESSION["carrito"] = [];
header("Location: ./vender.php?status=1");
?>
```

`

i don't know what this error is trying to tell me since is the first time that this error ocurred for me
the var_dump($_SESSION["carrito"]) IS
array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["codigo"]=> string(1) "1" ["descripcion"]=> string(7) "bozales" ["precioVenta"]=> string(6) "150.00" ["existencia"]=> string(6) "200.00" ["cantidad"]=> int(1) ["total"]=> string(6) "150.00" } }

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to access property on array not object, it should be like this:

```php
foreach ($_SESSION["carrito"] as $producto) {
    $total += $producto['total'];
    $sentencia->execute([$producto['id'], $idVenta, $producto['cantidad']]);
    $sentenciaExistencia->execute([$producto['cantidad'], $producto['id']]);
}
```

you access array keys like this `$arr['key']`, objects properties like this `$obj->property`, and it's an array